How to change content of a td tag to separate p tags by jQuery
I want to change the p tag content inside td tag to separate p tags, if the content has comma (separated by ',').
Current HTML:
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Ports</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>3 ports</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Types</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>1 VGA, 1 HDMI, 1 LAN</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

After update by jQuery:
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Ports</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>3 ports</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Types</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>1 VGA</p>
        <p>1 HDMI</p>
        <p>1 LAN</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Break apart the problem into smaller individual steps.  You're looking to target the <td> element in question, read the content of its child <p> element, split that content by comma into an array (trimming any leading/trailing whitespace on each), empty the contents of the <td>, and append each element of the array to the <td> in the form of a new <p> element.  When you try, where specifically do you get stuck?

I couldn't add multiple p tags inside the td tag. This was my problem.

You can select all the relevant paragraph elements, then use replaceWith.


$('table.shop_attributes > tbody > tr > td.value > p').replaceWith(
  (i, t) => t.split(', ').map(p => $('<p/>').text(p))
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_attributes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Ports</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>3 ports</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="label">Types</th>
      <td class="value">
        <p>1 VGA, 1 HDMI, 1 LAN</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



